# reloadRowsAtIndexPath setting different cell at reuse

Tags: ios, uitableview, custom-cell, reloaddata, reuseidentifier

I am reloading a cell using `reloadRowsAtIndexPath` when a button in that cell is pressed. Then tableView delegates are getting called twice. When I press the button first time, one of my subviews is getting removed. On second press, it is restored. On inspecting `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I am getting cell with different address. I am getting it back on second click(cell with same address). I doubt it is some issue with cell reuse. But if I am reloading entire table(using `reloadData`), there is no issue.

Comment: can you write code of  cell for row method

Comment: Please post the code for the cellForRowAtIndexPath: as well as the place where you call reloadRows

Comment: @CrazyDeveloper - Sorry, Project got NDA. Also the code contains internal methods too. Have you used reloadRowsAtIndexPath? Will it trigger twice the cell for row?

Comment: You should be able to extract the piece of code that is not sensitive but reproduces the claimed behavior. Also, this approach is excellent for debugging and testing your problem so anyway I suggest you to do so.

Answer (score 0):

`tableView.reloadData` fits the best!

Comment: Thats exactly what I am doing now. But when height changes, scrollViewDidScroll is called and causing some issues.